# Parsing english words from a large string of mixed numbers, letters, characters using nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have a large string full of mixed characters, numbers, letters, words such as `...\\u102e\\u1038\\u101c\\u1031\\u1015\\u102b\\u1090\\u101a\\u103a\\u104b","tree"\\u1021\\3d\\u1004\\u1039\\u1038\\u1006\\u102f\\u1076\\u1038\\u1031\\u103b\\u1015\\u102c\\u101b\\u101b\\u1204\\u1039 \\u101b\\u103d\\, "english": "label"',u101a\\u1060\\u101a\\u102c\\u1031\\u1030\\u108c\\, "hello world how are you doing."...hfpiuhfubE\\\`

My end goal is to have a list of every english word that appears in this string such as list = ['tree','english','label'..]
This is what I have tried, which is giving me the words repeated over and over again, this is definitely a problem with the way that I structured the function:

````
    tokens = [word.lower() for item in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(item)]
    filtered_tokens = []
    wordlist = nltk.corpus.words.words('en')
    parsed = []

    for token in tokens:
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
            filtered_tokens.append(token)
            for i in filtered_tokens:
                for m in wordlist:
                    if i == m:
                        parsed.append(i)
    
        return parsed```
````

Comment: That looks like part of a JSON array. Why not use `json.loads()` to convert it to a list, instead of trying to parse it this way?

Comment: Thank you so much... this is exactly what I wanted!